# JSP insert number and show them on page after click button

Tags: jsp

I have to do a simple thing but I really don't know how to do.

I have to make a jsp page where you have to insert 10 number, then click on a button "Add" which will print all the ten number on a div in the same page.

```
<form>
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="number" name="number">
</form>

<button>Add</button>

<div>Your numbers are: </div>
<div> <here will appear the ten numbers> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jsp is something executed on the server. If you want to change the content of a page you have to send to the server the proper information and wait for the server to respond. After your client received the response of the server you can show the output to the final user. In practically you can do two things:

1. refresh your entire page, that is send all the numbers to a servlet or a jsp page that performs a redirect to an identical page except for the div that shows the sum (look for jsp/servlet GET/POST request on google).
2. use Ajax and do the same thing but refreshing only a part of the page (in your case the div showing the sum, you can find very easy tutorials about ajax everywere)

there is a third way, the way that i wuold choose: use javascript and do not involve jsp at all, with javascript you can meet all your requirements without calling the server, this means that your calculation will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

Add

```
<div>Your numbers are: </div>
<div id="printedVal">
  <here will appear the ten numbers>
</div>


 $("#clicktoAdd").click(function() {
      var elem = '';
      $("input").each(function(i, el) {
        if (elem != undefined) {
          elem = elem + ',' + $(this).val();
        }
        $('#printedVal').text(elem.substring(1));
      });
    });
```

Hope this is helpful for you.